# SQL Server How to get Date Difference excluding Weekends and Holidays?

Tags: sql, sql-server, getdate

I have this table:

tbl_Sales

```
----------------------------------------
|Item_Code|Sold|Date                   |
|---------+----+-----------------------|
|BBPen100 |30  |2017-04-17 00:00:00.000|
|BBPen100 |21  |2017-04-13 00:00:00.000|
|BBPen100 |13  |2017-04-12 00:00:00.000|
|XSHIRT80 |0   |2017-04-17 00:00:00.000|
|XSHIRT80 |24  |2017-04-14 00:00:00.000|
|XSHIRT80 |9   |2017-04-13 00:00:00.000|
|XSHIRT80 |5   |2017-04-12 00:00:00.000| 
|YBSHADE7 |0   |2017-04-17 00:00:00.000| 
|YBSHADE7 |6   |2017-04-15 00:00:00.000| 
|YBSHADE7 |0   |2017-04-13 00:00:00.000| 
|YBSHADE7 |11  |2017-04-12 00:00:00.000| 
----------------------------------------
```

How can I get the last non-zero Sold value from the last 2 working days? This means that I need to exclude the Weekends and Holidays.
I have this table which consists holidays.

tbl_Holiday

```
-------------------------
|Holiday_Date           |
|-----------------------|
|2017-04-14 00:00:00.000|
|2017-05-01 00:00:00.000|
|2017-10-18 00:00:00.000|
|2017-12-25 00:00:00.000|
-------------------------
```

So for example today is 2017-04-18, the output should be like this:

```
---------------------
|Item_Code|Last_Sold|
|---------+---------|
|BBPen100 |30       |
|XSHIRT80 |9        |
|YBSHADE7 |0        |
---------------------
```

The goal is to get the last Sold value from LAST 2 working days, so the counting start on 2017-04-17.
Output analysis:

```
BBPen100-since it has value from last 1 working day (2017-04-17), that value will be retrieved.
XSHIRT80-Zero value from last 1 working day (2017-04-17)
        -2017-04-16 & 2017-04-15 are weekends
        -2017-04-14 is holiday
        -So value from 2017-04-13 will be retrieved.
YBSHADE7-Zero value from last 1 working day (2017-04-17)
        -2017-04-16 & 2017-04-15 are weekends
        -2017-04-14 is holiday
        -2017-04-13 has Zero value
        -2017-04-12 is beyond Last 2 working days
        -So value retrived should be Zero
```

Currently, I have this query:

```
SELECT Item_Code, Sold AS 'Last_Sold'
FROM tbl_Sales
WHERE CONVERT(date, [DATE]) = CASE
                                WHEN CONVERT(date, [DATE]) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) THEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()))
                                WHEN CONVERT(date, [DATE]) <> CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())) THEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()))
```

But of course, this would not meet the requirements.

Please help me resolve this.

IMPORTANT NOTE: Consider the holidays on weekends and what if I run the program on weekends or holidays.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `last 2 working days` ... which days of the week does this include?

Comment: for example if a holiday is at weekend, then next monday is not working day, isn't it?

Comment: @TriV no need to worry on that. In Holiday table, it is already applied. When holiday is sunday, then Monday will be the one in Holiday table. But if it is Saturday, Nothing's changed. And that is the one to consider.

Comment: Please update your question and show data which covers _every_ edge case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it

Sample data

```
DECLARE @SampleData as TABLE (Item_Code varchar(10), Sold int, Date datetime)
Insert into @SampleData VALUES
('BBPen100', 30,'2017-04-17 00:00:00.000'),
('BBPen100', 21,'2017-04-13 00:00:00.000'),
('BBPen100', 13,'2017-04-12 00:00:00.000'),
('XSHIRT80', 0 ,'2017-04-17 00:00:00.000'),
('XSHIRT80', 24,'2017-04-14 00:00:00.000'),
('XSHIRT80', 9 ,'2017-04-13 00:00:00.000'),
('XSHIRT80', 5 ,'2017-04-12 00:00:00.000'),
('YBSHADE7', 0 ,'2017-04-17 00:00:00.000'),
('YBSHADE7', 6 ,'2017-04-15 00:00:00.000'),
('YBSHADE7', 0 ,'2017-04-13 00:00:00.000'),
('YBSHADE7', 11,'2017-04-12 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @TblHoliday AS TABLE
(
   Holiday_Date date
)

INSERT INTO @TblHoliday
VALUES
('2017-04-14 00:00:00.000'),
('2017-05-01 00:00:00.000'),
('2017-10-18 00:00:00.000'),
('2017-12-25 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime = '2017-04-18 00:00:00'
```

You could calculate @2PreviousWorkingDays before @CurrentDate

```
-- 2 Previous Working Day with out Holiday
DECLARE @2PreviousWorkingDay date = CASE
                         WHEN datepart(dw,@CurrentDate) IN (2,3) THEN dateadd(day,-4, @CurrentDate)  -- 2 previous working day before monday
                         WHEN datepart(dw,@CurrentDate) IN (1) THEN dateadd(day,-3, @CurrentDate)   -- 2 previous working day before sunday
                         ELSE dateadd(day,-2, @CurrentDate) -- other day week
                       END
-- with holiday
SELECT @2PreviousWorkingDay = dateadd(day,0 - (SELECT count(1) FROM @TblHoliday th 
                      WHERE  th.Holiday_Date BETWEEN @2PreviousWorkingDay AND @CurrentDate
                      ANd datepart(dw,th.Holiday_Date) NOT IN (7,1) -- calculate only holiday that isn't weekend
                            )                            
                      , @2PreviousWorkingDay
```

And your desired result:

```
;with temps AS
(
SELECT *, row_number() over(PARTITION BY sd.Item_Code ORDER BY sd.[Date] DESC) AS Rn
FROM @SampleData sd
WHERE sd.[Date] >= @2PreviousWorkingDay -- 2 working days
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TblHoliday th WHERE th.Holiday_Date = Cast(sd.[Date] AS date)) -- not holiday
   AND datepart(dw,sd.[Date]) NOT IN (7,1) -- not weekend
   AND sd.Sold <> 0 -- not zero sold
)
SELECT sd.Item_Code, ISNULL(t.Sold,0) AS Sold FROM
(
   SELECT DISTINCT sd.Item_Code FROM @SampleData sd
) sd
LEFT JOIN temps t ON t.Item_Code = sd.Item_Code AND t.Rn = 1
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/GCJYH72713)

Comment: I am just getting an error with the semicolon beside WITH. When I remove it, still error.

Comment: You must use `WITH` with `;` before.  it is not caused by `;WITH`.

Comment: Got it! Just a missing Closing Parenthesis before semicolon. Thank you so much life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte1 AS(
    SELECT t.*
    FROM tbl_Sales t
    LEFT JOIN tbl_Holiday hd
        ON t.Date = hd.Holiday_Date
    WHERE hd.Holiday_Date IS NULL AND
          DATENAME(WEEKDAY, t.Date) <> 'Saturday' AND
          DATENAME(WEEKDAY, t.Date) <> 'Sunday'
),
WITH cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item_Code ORDER BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, this doesn't meet all the requirements like to not retrieve zero value in the last 2 days and if beyond 2 days, that should be zero

Comment: Your question is unclear.  This was the best I could do.