# SQL Server - Get Last Business Data excluding holidays and Weekends

Tags: sql-server

I use this query to get the last business date excluding weekends:

```
DECLARE @LastBizDate as DATETIME

SELECT @LastBizDate = (DATEADD(DAY, CASE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) 
                      WHEN 'Saturday' THEN -1 
                      WHEN 'Sunday' THEN -2 
                      ELSE -1 END, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE())))

SELECT @LastBizDate AS 'Last_Business_Date'
```

But how can I exclude the holidays?

I have this `tbl_Holidays` table with sample data:

```
-------------------------
|Holiday_Date           |
|-----------------------|
|2017-04-14 00:00:00.000|
|2017-05-01 00:00:00.000|
|2017-10-18 00:00:00.000|
|2017-12-25 00:00:00.000|
-------------------------
```

**Note**: no need to consider that when the holiday falls on Sunday, then Monday will be considered Off. Again, no need to consider that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could try my answer in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492452/sql-server-how-to-get-date-difference-excluding-weekends-and-holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a loop to do this.

After excluding saturday and sunday, you need to check whether the date is in the holiday table. Again you need to check the date (calculated after excluding from holiday table )falls on sunday and saturday.

```
DECLARE @last_wrk_day DATETIME
    ,@today DATETIME
DECLARE @TblHoliday AS TABLE (Holiday_Date DATE)

INSERT INTO @TblHoliday
VALUES ('2017-04-14 00:00:00.000')
    ,('2017-05-01 00:00:00.000')
    ,('2017-10-18 00:00:00.000')
    ,('2017-12-25 00:00:00.000')
    ,('2017-04-13 00:00:00.000')

SET @today = '2017-04-10 00:00:00.000' --getdate()
SET @last_wrk_day = dateadd(day, - 1, @today)

WHILE (
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 1
            FROM @TblHoliday
            WHERE Holiday_Date = @last_wrk_day
            ) = 1
        OR DATEPART(dw, @last_wrk_day) IN (1, 7)
        )
BEGIN
    SET @last_wrk_day = dateadd(day, - 1, @last_wrk_day)
END

SELECT @last_wrk_day
```

**OUTPUT**

2017-04-13 00:00:00.000

Comment: If 2017-04-13 is a holiday how can @last_wrk_day = 2017-04-13?

Comment: @CJ My Bad. The output I copied here is wrong. The above code will return "2017-04-07 00:00:00.000"