# Get list of dates that falls in End Of each Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get end of each month for the past 3 yrs from the current date excluding statutory holidays and weekends using table1 and table2. Table1 has all the dates ranging from year 2025-2017. Table2 has all the statutory holidays for the years ranging from 2025-2017.

How to create SQL script for to attain this result? Any suggestions could help. Expected result would be list of date last 3yrs of endofmonth excluding statutory holidays and weekends.

Table 1 has 2 columns, DateId and FullDate column

```
 DateID Fulldate

 1010392 2019-12-1
 1010393 2019-12-2
 1010394 2019-12-3
 1010395 2019-12-4
 .
 .
 101086 2019-12-31
```

Table 2 has 2 columns, DateId and Statutory_Holidays

```
 Date ID   Stat_Holidays
 101085     2019-12-25
 101086     2019-12-26
```

And the returned results should look like

```
WeekDay_FullDate_Past3yrs
2019-12-31
2020-1-31
2020-2-28
2020-3-31
```

Tried the below:

```
 select * from
 ( select a.Date from Table1 a where a.Date <= 
  '20221215' and a.Date >= DATEADD (YEAR, -3, getdate()) ) as t1
 join
 ( select EOMONTH(a.Date) as Date from Table1 a where a.Date <= '20221215' and a.Date >= DATEADD (YEAR, -3, getdate()) ) as t2 on t1.Date = t2.Date
```

tried the solution from the below link it dosen't solve my issue. I'm looking to get list of last workday of a month(excluding weekends and holiday) for the past 3yrs
[SQL Server - Get Last Business Data excluding holidays and Weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510019/sql-server-get-last-business-data-excluding-holidays-and-weekends)

Comment: [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I need to get the End of month for past 3 yrs excluding weekends and holidays. I need help on iteration?

Comment: Anything that deals with weekends / holiday is best with a calendar table

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have 2 table, one table with all dates for the past 3 yrs. other table holds only the holidays for the past 3 yrs. I need help on how to iterate through the rows to get the last working day of the month, if EOM falls in weekend or holiday had to pick the last working day

Comment: I tried this but need some suggestion

select * from 
(
select a.FullDate  from ref.date a 
where a.fulldate <= '20221215' and a.fulldate >= DATEADD (YEAR, -3, getdate()) 
) as t1
join
(
select EOMONTH(a.fulldate) as Fulldate from ref.date a 
where a.fulldate <= '20221215' and a.fulldate >= DATEADD (YEAR, -3, getdate()) 
) as t2 on t1.FullDate = t2.FullDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by month and year and take the max date (excluding holidays and weekends):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE = '20221215';

WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT MAX(Date ) as EOMDate
    FROM Table1 
    WHERE DATEPART(weekday,Date) NOT IN (6,7)
    AND Date NOT IN (SELECT Date FROM Table2)
    GROUP BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cte.EOMDate BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR,-3,@CurrentDate) AND @CurrentDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work and give you the last working day for each month in your main table. Just filter by the desired time period:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES FullDate
FROM Table1
WHERE FullDate NOT IN (SELECT Stat_Holidays FROM Table2) -- not holiday
    AND DATEPART(weekday, FullDate) NOT IN (7, 1) -- not saturday and sunday
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR(FullDate), MONTH(FullDate) ORDER BY FullDate DESC)
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it's giving me 1 week before the last week, for eg for the year 2019 it's returning 2019-12-20 but the last working date is 2019-12-31

Comment: @DavidJones it is not working only for December 2019?

Comment: It's not working for any yrs, I need list of end of month dates excluding weekend and holidays for the past 3yrs from the given date

Comment: @DavidJones It depents on your date first setting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

Check this with your table name and column names.

```
select  year(dates) _Year ,month(dates) _Month,EOMONTH(dates) endofMOnth from tabledate1 where DATENAME(DW, dates) not in ('Saturday','Sunday') 
and EOMONTH(dates)  not in (select holidaydate from tableholidays)
Group by year(dates),month(dates),EOMONTH(dates) 
order by year(dates) ,month(dates)
```